# React - nested objects and useState is mutating original state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created radio buttons that filter the data when selected. When I filter the nested objects, the originalData seems to get mutated. So when I select All again it doesn't revert back to the original data.
Can anyone see why the filteredData and originalData are both updating?
Thanks in advance for your help.

I have read " if your object contains nested objects, those nested objects will be copied by reference instead of by value. So if you change the nested object, you’ll mutate the original object. " But I am unsure if I can update my code or I need a library for this?

```
   const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
            type: 'All',
            risk: [],
            difficulty: 'All'
        })
    const [originalData, setOriginalData] = useState({...props.offerCategories}) 
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState({...originalData})
    
    useEffect(()=> {
            const{type, risk, difficulty} = filters;
    
            if(type !== 'All'){
                    let tempList = {...filteredData}
                    filteredData.offer_sub_categories.forEach((category, i)=> {
                        const list = category.offers.map((offer)=> {
                            const offerTags = offer.offer_tags.filter((tag)=> tag.Tag === type)
                            if(offerTags.length === 1) return offer
                        }).filter(tag => tag != undefined);
                        tempList.offer_sub_categories[i].offers = list;
                    })
                    setFilteredData(tempList)
                }
            } 
            if(type === 'All'){
                setFilteredData(originalData)
            }
            
            
        }, [filters])
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would modify the `originalData` value. Maybe the value of `props.offerCategories` is being modified somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spread operator doesn't clone nested objects. You can update your code to

```
   const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
            type: 'All',
            risk: [],
            difficulty: 'All'
        })
    const [originalData, setOriginalData] = useState({...props.offerCategories}) 
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState({...originalData})
    
    useEffect(()=> {
            const{type, risk, difficulty} = filters;
    
            if(type !== 'All'){
                    const offer_sub_categories = filteredData.offer_sub_categories.map((category, i)=> {
                        const offers = category.offers.filter((offer)=> {
                            const offerTags = offer.offer_tags.filter((tag)=> tag.Tag === type)
                            return offerTags.length === 1;
                        });
                        return {...category,offers};
                    });
                setFilteredData({...filteredData,offer_sub_categories});
            } 
            if(type === 'All'){
                setFilteredData(originalData)
            }
            
            
        }, [filters])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to know. Kindly accept the answer too